# How to define a value converter for a combobox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to load the values of the `DistanceRoundoffs` List into a `ComboBox`. The values are in `mm` but I want to display them in `cm` so I'll need to use a value converter.

I don't know how and where to use it. Should I define it in `ItemsSource` or `SelectedItem`?

I don't need the code for value converter; Just the implementation in XAML for the current combobox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DistanceRoundoffs}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DistanceRoundoff, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, 
                    Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiUnitConverter}" ConverterParameter="{x:Static enumerations:Quantity.Length}">
                            <Binding Path="RebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff"/>
                            <Binding Path="CurrentTargetUnit"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

private List<double> distanceRoundoffs = new List<double> {25, 50};
public List<double> DistanceRoundoffs
{
    get { return distanceRoundoffs; }
    set
    {
        distanceRoundoffs = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DistanceRoundoffs");
    }
}

private double distanceRoundoff;
public double DistanceRoundoff
{
    get { return distanceRoundoff; }
    private set
    {
        distanceRoundoff= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DistanceRoundoff");
    }
}
```

Comment: And did you read a tutorial? This is not a coding service, if you need something coded, hire a developer. If you want to learn, read a tutorial, *try it* and come here with a specific question. "Please code it for me" is not a question.

Comment: @nvoigt Yes I did read tutorials. But there are times when you are stuck no matter how many tutorials you have read. And I didn't ask for the code I just asked where I should use the converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the converter in the `ItemTemplate` of the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource UnitConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thank you Clemens, actually this was the method I used initially but XAML doesn't recognize `RebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff` when used in the datatemplate. I updated the question.

Comment: And now I shall guess what that is?

Comment: There is no problem with the datacontext, the below code for example works fine:                                         `<TextBox>
<TextBox.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding>
                                                    <Binding Path="RebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="CurrentTargetUnit"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBox.Text>
                                        </TextBox>`

Comment: Anyway, the DataContext of each ComboBoxItem is set to the respective element of the ItemsSource collection, i.e. a `double` value. However, a double has no `RebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff` or `CurrentTargetUnit` properties.

Comment: The answer suits my asked question but I'm getting exceptions. I'll try to put this together and ask a relevant question.

Comment: Please make sure you include *all relevant details* in your questions. I wouldn't have written this answer after your question edit, where you added the XAML part.

Comment: @Clemens Sorry about that. I was a bit confused how to ask this question. I asked another question related to this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731852/combox-doesnt-get-updated-in-wpf?noredirect=1#comment43875086_27731852