# Combox doesn't get updated in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've used the below code to `Bind` the `ItemsSource` of a `ComboBox` to `DistanceRoundoffs` list.

I have also bound the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` to `RebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff` property.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DistanceRoundoffs}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SettingsViewModel.RebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, 
                    Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

private List<double> distanceRoundoffs = new List<double> { 25, 50};
public List<double> DistanceRoundoffs
{
    get { return distanceRoundoffs; }
    set
    {
        distanceRoundoffs = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DistanceRoundoffs");
    }
}

private double rebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff;
public double RebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff
{
    get { return rebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff; }
    set
    {
        rebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("RebarsVerticalDistanceRoundoff");
    }
}
```

I have also implemented an IValueConverter to convert the values of the `ComboBox` to another unit. The converter accepts the `double` value and changes its unit based on a parameter named `lfactor`.

```
public class LengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var length = (double)value;

        var lfactor = Building.LengthFactor;

        return string.Format("{0}",length / lfactor);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The `lfactor` parameter is obtained when we change the unit by another combobox listed below.

```
private void Units_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GetLengthFactor();
    // Building.LengthFactor is changed here! Later used in LengthConverter
}
```

The initial values of the DistanceRoundoffs are in `mm` : 25,50

When I change the UnitComboBox, then `Units_OnSelectionChanged` fires but the `DistanceRoundoffs` doesn't get updated.

Comment: Look for binding errors in output window. You're not giving much to go on here.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa How can I do that?

Comment: Start debugging, then click the "VIEW" header, then "Output". The output window should appear and show errors and other information from the debugger.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa It is not showing any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original approach with a MultiBinding was quite ok. You just have to make sure that the individual bindings are correct. In particalur, the "unit factor" binding needs its source object to be specified.

Assumed that there is a `LengthFactor` property in the same view model that holds the `DistanceRoundoffs` property, the DataTemplate would look like this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LengthConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="."/>
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.LengthFactor"
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

LengthConverter now implements `IMultiValueConverter` and its Convert method would look like this:

```
public object Convert(
    object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return ((double)values[0] *(double)values[1]).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens, this solved my problem. Is `DataContext` as static variable that always refers to the current DataContext? I hadn't seen its use in XAML so far.

Comment: It's just the `DataContext` property of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is not aware of the relationship between the selected unit and the display of your distance roundoffs. As long as there's no signal that `DistanceRoundoffs` has changed, it sees no reason to update that combobox.

So you'll have to give it a signal by raising a `PropertyChanged` event for `DistanceRoundoffs` when the selected unit is changed, e.g. in the setter of your selected-unit property.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your viewmodel, e.g. the `DistanceRoundoffs` and the units/selected-unit properties?

Comment: You're reacting to the unit selection change in your code-behind. Are you treating the code-behind as the DataContext of your control, or is the `DistanceRoundoff` property in a separate view-model class?